# Can't add angular app dependency in plunkr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plunker

I'm trying to create a plunkr that uses AngularJS and UI-Bootstrap. The preview doesn't evaluate {{}} bindings as soon as I want to add the "ui-bootstrap" dependency. In fact, as soons as I enter anything as dependency ("ui-bootstrap" or even ""), the code fails. If I leave the array empty, everything works fine.

```
angular.module("myApp", [/*leaving this empty works, otherwise bindings wont be resolved*/]).controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
        //controller stuff
    }
]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/38sWnHVSS3lfYSB5oPzp?p=preview

What's wrong there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your plunker you have used `ui-bootstrap`, whereas the documentation says to use: `ui.bootstrap`.

It should be

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])
```

Comment: Woops...you are right. Anyway, if I change that, plunker doesn't show any preview :o Something seems to be still wrong.

Comment: Ok, got it. I also had the ui-bootstrap cdn path wrong. Now it works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/QocibRNIGFl1DkdGzVnZ?p=preview Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A working example with accortion in place you can find [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cgloVsMrIUlM0rfpDbjl?p=preview).
The issue why bootstrap wasn't compiling the accortion is due to the default template that it needs for creation. When using just the link

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

It can't find the two templates. So I downloaded the angular-boostrap code WITH templates and added it to the plunkr + injected the dependency and it's working properly.
Please note, the nesting suggested to be removed was also done in this example, so in controller there is only:

```
 $scope.groups = [
    {heading: "A", content: "This is the first accordion group", opened:true},
    {heading: "B", content: "This is the second accordion group", opened: false},
    {heading: "C", content: "This is the last accordion group", opened:false}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look and it seems that you're nesting it way too much.

```
$scope.MainCtrl = {
      groups : [
        {heading: "A", content: "This is the first accordion group", opened:true},
        {heading: "B", content: "This is the second accordion group", opened: false},
        {heading: "C", content: "This is the last accordion group", opened:false}
      ]
    };
```

Here you're defining `MainCtrl` as a new object, then nesting groups inside.

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.groups = [
        {heading: "A", content: "This is the first accordion group", opened:true},
        {heading: "B", content: "This is the second accordion group", opened: false},
        {heading: "C", content: "This is the last accordion group", opened:false}
    ];

  });
```

Working: http://plnkr.co/edit/Le2awE24GJiM3N6h8uQO?p=preview

Comment: As you can see here, I have removed the internal-nesting. Now, you need to define `groups` to be an immediate object available to scope; in your code, it wasn't. However, the fix is trivial and you can make out what I have done! :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into it. Unfortunately that's not the issue. Try to add a dependency like "ui-bootstrap" to the angular app, it will break the bindings: http://plnkr.co/edit/gTAhW1PGCEABYYw5n6dl?p=preview

Comment: @Fidel90 it will be "ui.bootstrap" as dependency. Check this https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started